# Applet loads jars from different domains; has problem loading resources (e.g. images) from jars

Tags: resources, applet, load, dns

I have a sandboxed Applet, but that should not make a difference.

The Applet consists of 2 jars. If I host both files on the same domain1 all is fine. Due to certain special circumstances I need to host jar2 on a different domain2.

In the applet tag I list both files archive="jar1.jar, http://domain2.com/jar2.jar".

First it seems to be working great. Both jars are loaded and everything works fine. Still, as soon as I try to access a resource (like an image) from INSIDE one of the jars there is a problem.

How do I get resources from my jars?
I get resources by first getting an URL for the location of the resource:

public static URL getURL(String name)  {return ResUtils.class.getResource(path);}

If I host both jars on domain1 this method returns an URL. When hosted on two domains getURL(...) returns NULL which then results in an Exception when fetching the resource:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I guess ResUtils.class.getResource uses its Classloader to return an URL. For some reason when hosting both jars on two domains add calls to getRessource() return NULL.

So my question is:

- Why does getURL return NULL?

Is the Java plugin designed to disallow hosting those jars on different domains? 
How do I have to load my resources when I host the jars on different domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
      ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      URL url = cl.getResource("imagename.gif");
      System.out.println("URL is: " + url);
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Using the context classloader is generally the best way to load images from jar files.

Edit1:  BTW, I am surprised that the first suggestion did not work.  If memory serves me right, the Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() suggestion should have given you a reference to a classloader that could have located resources from either jar file.

Edit2:  none of the above works in this case.  Curiosity got the best of me so I had to try it.  The plugin classloader just seems too confused to load resources from jar files hosted on another server, even though it has no problems loading classes.  What I found is that a manual method **does** work to load resources like this:

```
  String manualString = "jar:http://spider.grunt.webhop.net/clubjar.jar!/club.gif";
  URL manualURL = new URL(manualString);
  BufferedImage buf = ImageIO.read(manualURL);
  System.out.println("manual buf: " +buf);
```

To me, this looks like a bug with the plugin classloader.  We should be able to use the classloader getResource() or getResourceAsStream() methods to locate a valid resource.  Not so in this case.  The ImageIO class can read our manual URL, but the classloader cannot give us one.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. At least I don't feel anymore like a total idiot. This manualString you basically just typed in, or is there a good way to get it? Btw, the jar from the first domain CAN load resources from inside itself.

Comment: Can you post a link to you applet example that does not work?

Comment: https://iris.dev.java.net also uses jars from different domains. I can only guess that they do not need to load resources from jars from the second domain.

Comment: I basically just typed in the url.  The format is here:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html

I did notice that the applet would be able to load images from the 2nd jar file when running locally under appletviewer.  The same applet fails when running through a browser.  I did not actually deploy the applet anywhere public.  I was able to see the same results you see running the applet locally through firefox.

Comment: I didn't even try appletviewer because the results are always so much different from what you expect running it on a server.

Comment: inquiring minds want to know - did this solution work for you?  If so, could you accept this answer?

Comment: Sure - I'll accept it. I wonder if there is a way to automatically generate the URL String: "jar:http://spider.grunt.webhop.net/clubjar.jar!/club.gif" or at least parts of it???

Comment: Also marked it as helpful :)
Do you think we should file a bug with Sun?

Answer (score 0):

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); doesn't solve my problem.

All my resources are in the same 'res' folder/package - same as the Class to fetch them: ResUtils (see source below).

If a class in jar1 from domain1 calls ResUtils.getImageIcon("trash.gif");  getURL(...) returns an URL: url -> jar:http://domain1/bun.jar!/res/trash.gif

If a class in jar2 from domain2 calls ResUtils.getImageIcon("trash.gif"); getURL(...) returns an NULL: url -> null

```
package res;

public class ResUtils {
       private static final String PATH =  "/" + (ResUtils.class.getPackage().getName().replace(".", "/")) + "/";
         public static URL getURL(String name)  {return ResUtils.class.getResource(PATH + name);}
          public static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String name) {
           return new ImageIcon(getBufferedImage(name));
       }

       public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(String name) {
           try {
               URL url = getURL(name);
               return ImageIO.read(url);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return new BufferedImage(10,10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Your ResUtils.getURL() is using the classloader that loaded the ResUtils class to load all of your images.  ResUtils must be located in jar1 in your case.  I believe the Java plugin will use separate classloaders to load jars from different domains.  Your ResUtils class only knows about one classloader.  See next answer for the code.

Comment: BTW, your code section is much easier to read if place all of your code using the code tag

Comment: I know. I tried to do that, but it only decorated 'package res;'

Back to the URL problem. Nothing works. I tried now every possible combination. Nada - all URLs returned are Null.

Even a simple URL url = Class2.class.getResource("res/trash2.gif");
 does not work, although trash2.gif is located in jar2.jar hosted on domain2.

I would be happy to be proven wrong but until then I think it is impossible to load any resources from classes in jar2, even if the resources are in jar2.


I have Java 1.6_u14 - perhaps they changed something.

Comment: I ran into the same issue pasting code.  The simplest way to put all the code into a code block is to first paste the code into the edit window, select the code block, then press the code button.  I would edit your post to fix it, but it requires a higher reputation.

Anyway, I do remember seeing this issue from somewhere before.  Java 1.6_u10 changed quite a bit under the covers.  I believe there is a documented issue regarding this.  Anyway, do you really need to load jar files from multiple domains?  Why not just host them all together?

Comment: Ok, I tried to fix code formatting. Thanks! I just tested it with pre-Update10 Java6 and even Java5. Everywhere the same problem.

I have setup a minimal testcase with two jar on two domains and I still cannot solve the problem . I guess I will need to convince someone to setup a similar system without my intervention to check this out.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a solution I found to work.  Yes, I even tried it.